# ruby on rails add in head path for favicon

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-6, favicon

I have add my folder in `app/assets`.

The path for my favicon is `app/assets/my_assets/img/ico/lotus.png`

In my views : **app/views/layouts** :
in the `<head>`
I try to add the path but that doesn't work.

I've try this :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/my_assets/img/ico/lotus.png">
```

and this :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../../assets/my_assets/img/ico/lotus.png">
```

Maybe it's not the good way or the good path.
Someone can help me ? I have to understand how that works because after i got some other image on my website and i need to put the good path to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag asset_path('lotus.png') %>
```

Comment: Thanks you, and if in one of my views i want to do same for an images how do it ? Have you some ressources ? I mean instead `favicon_link_tag`

Comment: for an image it is <%= image_tag asset_path('your-image.png') %>.
The Ruby on Rails official guide is very useful: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/
And there are many great tutorials/books/videos everywhere ;)